# ¿Existe un sitio dedicado a Linux en Stack Exchange?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange

Llevo unas horas buscando un foro de Stack Exchange dedicado a Linux, pero no encuentro nada.

¿Puede ser que esté restringido por países o algo?¿acaso existe algún sitio dedicado?

Comment: Mira una búsqueda rápida y lo encontré https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Esta pregunta en realidad pertenece a [meta]. En StackOverflow hay etiquetas para hacer preguntas de programación específicas de linux. Para otro tipo de consultas, existe el sitio [linux & unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) en la red StackExchange, pero solo acepta preguntas en Inglés.

Comment: Me disculpo por los problemas causados, ahora soy consciente de lo que he hecho, y pido perdón a la comunidad

Comment: Existen muchismos sitios creados para muchas cosas,puedes visitar [stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-newest) alli puedes ver el listado

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existe alguno, todos ellos en inglés:

- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) para temas de Ubuntu.
- [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) para administración de sistemas y redes.
- [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) para uso a nivel usuario de todos los sistemas operativos.
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) para todo lo relacionado con sistemas *nix.

Comment: El de Unix & Linux es el más amplio y suele ser el más útil para asuntos linuxeros.